# ajax mvc form authentication redirect issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, form-authentication

I am trying to handle the failed ajax request in MVC form authentication. I've added the following code in Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = new HttpRequestWrapper(Context.Request);
        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        }
    }
```

and on the main layout, I've added the following code

```
 $(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
            if (request.status == 401) {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "Login", "Account" )';
            }
         });
```

**Issue 1:**  On normal calls the form autheication redirects to the login page along with a return url which will help user to return to the same page he last visited before expiry. http://localhost:53733/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fUserList

Where as during ajax call since I redirect using jQuery, it http://localhost:53733/Account/Login. How can do ensure even in ajax call it redirects to login page along with return url

**Issue 2:**  Also the local ajax function error handler fires before the global ajax error handler. This results in displaying error on the page before navigating to the login page. Not sure how to handle this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may send the current url as the returnUrl

```
var u = '@Url.Action( "Login", "Account" )?ReturnUrl='+window.location.href;
window.location.href = u;
```

Remember, after successful login, your Login action method will redirect to the returnUrl value, which will be a totally new GET request. So user will see the page as a new page load (it will loose any changes you made in the page before getting redirected)

For the second issue, In your local ajax function, do not handle if `request.status == 401`

Something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    type: "post"
}).done(function(f) {
    console.log('done');
}).fail(function(a, b, c) {
    if (a.status !== 401) {
       // Handle locally as needed.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any global solution for second issue. There are lot of ajax calls which I need to modify.

Comment: @TechJerk I think you need to do that.otherwise both will be executed(first local,second global)

Comment: window.location.href gets the complete url http://localhost:53733/?ReturnUrl=http://localhost:53733/User/UserList. I am expecting something similar to how it looks using form authentication  http://localhost:53733/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fUser%2fUserList . This will help me to have generalized code logic in jQuery to handle user validation along with returnURL